# What's the element in position n of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have this function which gives me the element at given position in a list and need to rewrite it with cond instead of if. Also I want to change it a bit so If I give a negative value it returns nil for example

```
(getn 2 '(a b c)) => (c)
```

```
(getn -1 '(a b c)) => nil
```

The function :

```
(defun getn (n lst)
   (if 
      (zerop n)
      (car lst)
      (getn (1- n) (cdr lst)) ) )
```

I did that but doesn't work :

```
(defun getn (nb liste)
  (cond
     ((= 0 nb) liste)
  (getn (1- n) (cdr liste)) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first version is almost right. Note that when you call getn recursively you are shortening the list, so there will be a point where you are passing nil as the lst argument. You have to check for this condition before anything else and return nil if lst is nil.
cond is like a list of sequential if's. In your case you can write:

```
(cond ((null lst) nil)
      ((< n 0) nil)
      ((= n 0) (car lst))
      ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification ! Also my problems comes from the fact I need to write it with cond (not if) and I'm having issue to go from one to the other as im not super familiar with lisp yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun getn (n lst)
  (cond ((or (null lst) (< n 0)) nil)
        ((= n 0) (car lst))
        (t (getn (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))
```

For the case, that the nth element of the list is itself `nil`,
in lisp often one sends additional information. A second value, which is `t`,
if an element was found, and `nil` if no element was found.
So `nil; t` means the nth element was `nil`, while `nil; nil` means no element
was found.

```
(defun getn (n lst)
  (cond ((or (null lst) (< n 0)) (values nil nil))
        ((= n 0) (values (car lst) t))
        (t (getn (- n 1) (cdr lst)))))
```

```
[8]> (getn 1 '(1 nil 3))
NIL ;
T
;; an element was found -> T as second value, and the element was `nil`
[9]> (getn 1 '(1))
NIL ;
NIL
;; no element was found -> nil as second value, and therefore first value is also `nil`.
```

A very good book to learn recursive thinking and programming in lisp is `The little schemer` or the older version `the little lisper`. I learned through it thinking recursively.